# Is it possible to make a tikiz's school book axes in logarithmic coordinate?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I'm wondering if it's possible to do a plot like this with tikz, (or with pgfplot):

[image]

I need some help, thanks

This is a start:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{semilogxaxis}[xmin=0,xmax=10e8,ymin=100,ymax=900,axis lines=left, xlabel={$\log N$},ylabel={$\log\sigma_a$}]
\addplot [dashed,black]{700};
\addplot [dashed,black]{330};
\end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your question leaves all the effort to our community, even typing the essentials of a TeX document such as `\documentclass{}...\begin{document}` etc. As it is, most of our users will be very reluctant to touch your question, and you are left to the mercy of our procrastination team who are very few in number and very picky about selecting questions. You can improve your question by adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that more users can copy/paste onto their systems to work on. If no hero takes the challenge we might have to close your question.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way of getting something similar:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmode=log, ymode=log,
    xmin=1e4,xmax=1.9e8,
    ymin=1e1,ymax=1.9e4,
    axis lines=left,
    xlabel={$N$},ylabel={$\sigma_a$},
    grid=major,
    clip mode=individual,
    yticklabel={\empty},
    tick label style={text height=2ex}, % For proper vertical alignment
    extra x ticks={3e6},
    extra x tick labels={$N_{CR}$},
    extra y ticks={9e1},
    extra y tick labels={$\sigma_{(L)}$},
    extra tick style={
        grid=none,
        tick label style={ font=\boldmath}
    },
]

\addplot [thick, black] table {
N sigma
1e4 5e3
1e5 2.5e3
3e6 9e1
1.9e8 9e1
};

\node [font=\boldmath, left] at (axis cs:1e4,5e3) {$A$};
\node [font=\boldmath, above] at (axis cs:1e5,2.5e3) {$B$};
\node [font=\boldmath, anchor=-120] at (axis cs:6e6,9e1) {$C_R$};
\node [font=\boldmath, above] at (axis cs:8e7,9e1) {$D$};

\draw [densely dashed] (axis cs:1e4,9e1) -| (axis cs:3e6,1e1);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice! This could help me a lot. But I don't understand how to inser the labels A, B, C_R, D

Comment: They're placed using the lines `\node [<options>] at (<coordinate>) {<text>};`.

Answer (score 0):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{semilogxaxis}[
    width = \columnwidth, height = 0.7\columnwidth,
    xmin = 1, xmax = 1e10,
    ymin = 100, ymax = 900,
    xlabel = {$\log N$}, ylabel = $\log \sigma_a$,
    axis on top=true,
    axis lines=left,
    xtick={1,10,1e2,1e3,1e4,1e5,1e6,1e7,1e8},
    xticklabels={$0$,$10$,$10^2$,$10^3$,$10^4$,$10^5$,$10^6$,$10^7$,$10^8$},
    ytick={700,630,470,330},
    yticklabels={$\sigma_R$,630,$\sigma_S$,$\sigma_D$},
]
\addplot [very thick, black] table {
N sigma
1 700
1000 630
1e7 330
1e10 330
};
\node [anchor=south west] at (axis cs:1000,630) {$F$};
\filldraw[black] (axis cs:1000,630) circle(1.3pt);
\node [anchor=south west] at (axis cs:10^7,330) {$G$};
\filldraw[black] (axis cs:10^7,330) circle(1.3pt);


\node [anchor=south]  at (axis cs:10^9,330) {$\sigma_m=0$};




\draw [dashed] (axis cs:1,330) -| (axis cs:1e7,100);
\draw [dashed] (axis cs:1,630) -| (axis cs:1e3,100);


\end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```